# Rename dataframe columns by spliting its names and melting dataframe afterwards

Tags: r, ggplot2, rename

Example dataframe:

```
       col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
f1     0.1    0.2    0.3    0.4
f2     0.01   0.02   0.03  0.04
f3     0.001  0.002  0.003 0.004
```

I want to rename columns by splitting its names with `sep="_"` to get this:

```
       1      2      3      4
f1     0.1    0.2    0.3    0.4
f2     0.01   0.02   0.03   0.04
f3     0.001  0.002  0.003  0.004
```

Then I'd like to plot density for each column (f.name vs f.value) on the same plot (for instance: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_freqpoly-11.png) so I guess I need to melt it into something like this:

```
col   f.name    f.value    
1     f1        0.1
2     f1        0.2
3     f1        0.3
4     f1        0.4
1     f2        0.01
2     f2        0.02
3     f2        0.03
4     f2        0.04
1     f3        0.001
2     f3        0.002
3     f3        0.003
4     f3        0.004
```

Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Without testing the code, use packages 'dplyr' and 'tidyr'. Where `df` is your input *data frame*, the following should work:

```
df %>% gather(col, val, starts_with('col')) %>% 
  separate(col, into=c('nah','col'), sep='_') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=val, colour=col)) + geom_freqpoly()
```